# How can I fit two out of phase data sets to an envelope?

Tags: fitting, data

My situation is similar to having a Cos and Sin functions that would combine to the profile of the envelope but the envelope is offset horizontally by some dt.

It would be something like a*Cos(t+dt)+ b*Sin(t+dt)=Envelope(t), I want to find the coefficients and the time shift {a,b,dt}.

I have 2 data sets(lists) for the two input data sets and the data set for the envelope. How can I fit this? Using a NonLinearModelFit cannot fit this many functions at once.

Comment: Please share your data.

Comment: Here are MSE answers that might be of interest: [(1)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/173351/34008), [(2)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/106173/34008).